# Advise for reading skills

Tags: reading

I want to develop my reading ability and is there a spesific site which enables me to read whatever I am interested in with a formal writing( I want this as I also wanna learn new words which is picked very studiously )

Comment: Just a note: "wanna" is purely informal.

Comment: I don't know if I've misunderstood something, but it seems like you might want to use Google with a search string that's in English. That should bring up articles on the topic you're interested in in English. If you're interested in news, try the BBC or the New York Times. English Wikipedia is good, too. You can probably find free ebooks online somewhere as well, written by native speakers of English. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Where I can reach those ebooks from?